# mount: unknown filesystem type 'vmhgsf'

Tags: centos, vmware, fedora, vmware-player

I'm trying to mount my Windows shared folder in CentOS using command:

```
~mount -t vmhgfs .host:/shared-folder /var/www/html/
```

Unfortunately I get :

```
~mount: unknown filesystem type 'vmhgfs'
```

error. I tried to use:

```
~/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse /mnt
```

but mountpoint is not empty...

Is there any way to mount this folder on VMware player?

Comment: `sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse /mnt` works for me on Fedora to mount VMWare Windows 10 host folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyb

Try this:

```
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared-folder /var/www/html/
```

you might need to use **sudo** on this

Answer (score 1):

Working from a MacBook Pro running Big Sur and using VMware to host the virtual machine with CentOS 7 operating system. Had issues with loading in shared folders after VMware tools were installed. What worked for me is to use this exact command:

sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other

Hope this saves others the trouble of tracking down this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The below is working perfectly fine for me. Might be useful for someone.

Already I have mapped the required folders in "SharedFolder" settings. But it was not showing up.
Additionally running this command shares the windows directories.

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /home/user/win -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

Comment: After mounting the host shared folder to /path/to/my/MY_DIRECTORY/ , I lose access to MY_DIRECTORY. I cannot 'cd' into it - it give no such file or directory error. Running 'ls -al' on MY_DIRECTORY, I see a bunch of '?' in the permissions section and the owners section. Any idea what I might be missing ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!